# Excluding file type associations in USMT 10

Tags: usmt

I am using USMT 10 and have successfully migrated a user profile.  However, the new profile resets the default file associations for most applications back to the Windows 10 defaults (Edge, Photos, etc).  For example, by default we use Adobe Reader for PDF's, but on sign in pdf's are reset to Edge as the default viewer.

We have established a default file association xml as part of our OSD which is working just fine.  It's only profiles that are migrated with USMT that are breaking.  New profiles on the system are working as intended.

Is there any way to exclude the users file associations during migration?